# Deleting from SQL table with multiple column value checkings

Tags: c#, row, sql-delete

I want to delete a row from an SQL table with multiple column value checking.  I know how to do with it a single column value:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourDatabaseConnectionString");

string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE ColumnID = @ColumnID";

try{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnID", "SomeValueHere");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
finally {
    connection.Close();
}
```

However, what is the syntax for multiple column value checking?  Also, how should I format the values if they are of Date (SQL) and Time7 (SQL) format?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `AND` and `OR`? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I mean AND, but I suppose OR works in the same manner?  =/

Answer (score 1):

Add one more clause to the where condition. If you want to delete record which matches both condition, use **`AND`** ,and if you want to delete record which matches either one of the condition , then use **`OR`**

Query to check both condition

```
string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE
          ColumnID = @ColumnID AND ColumnName2=@SecondValue";
```

Query to check either one condition

```
string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE 
            ColumnID = @ColumnID OR ColumnName2=@SecondValue";
```

So your code will be something like this

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YourDatabaseConnectionString"))
{

    string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE ColumnID = @ColumnID AND ColumnName2=@SecondValue";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnID", "SomeValueHere");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondValue", "OtherValue");

     try
     {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        //log error
     }    
}
```